# break resulting in an infinite for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, break

I'm making a project for an online course. I don't want the computer-generated coordinates(xOfCompShips, yOfCompShips) to repeat themselves or be the same as those inputted by the user(xOfPlayerShips, yOfPlayerShips). So in case, the same coordinates are generated the if statement would decrease the value of i and make the loop run once more, replacing the duplicated coordinates. By printing lines for debugging I found out that the break statement seems to break the for loop with k and the control goes back to the for loop with i and without any new values being assigned to xOfCompShips,yOfCompShips(or perhaps same values being reassigned to them), the control goes back to the for loop with k and again back to the for loop with i and it keeps going back and forth.

I tried removing the break statement but then if the first random coordinates are a duplicate pair, the array is accessed for index = -1.

```
for(int i = 0; i < xOfCompShips.length; i++) {
    xOfCompShips[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    yOfCompShips[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    for(int k = 0; k < xOfPlayersShips.length; k++) {
        if((xOfCompShips[i] == xOfCompShips[k] && yOfCompShips[i] == yOfCompShips[k]) 
                || (xOfCompShips[i] == xOfPlayersShips[k] && yOfCompShips[i] == yOfPlayersShips[k])){
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect new random values are to be assigned to xOfCompShips and yOfCompShips each the if statement is executed.

Comment: Have you run this through your IDE's debugger to see what values all your variables are holding as you step through the loop? This should prove most instructive, I'd think

Comment: You are changing i in your if statement and looping with i. That is what is causing your infinite loop. You shouldn’t change your looping variable inside your loop.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to manually update the loop counter (`i`) inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * C) is the wrong way to do it, this doesn't get you quite uniform output, and it's also needlessly complicated. Make an instance of `java.util.Random` (and don't keep recreating it; make one instance once, and reuse it), and call `rnd.nextInt(10)` on that.
2. you loop k from 0 to xOfPlayersShips, and then use k as index to `xOfCompShips`. I doubt that's right.
3. as part of your loop, you say: if (xOfCompShips[i] == xOfCompShips[k] && yOfCompShips[i] == yOfCompShips[k]) *restart loop*. if i and k are the same, obviously that is true. i starts at 0, k starts at 0.. 0 == 0.

A run with a debugger would have shown you this rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot this completely solved my problem! I'm a complete newbie at this and frankly, don't currently know how to use a debugger. Though now that's my number one priority.

Comment: @SahejSingh: yep, now is the best time to learn debugger use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also breaking out of the outer loop (i.e. k--;), if I understand correctly (which I don't think I do), you're changing i over and over but k is always the same triggering the loop to change i more.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < xOfCompShips.length; i++) {
  xOfCompShips[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  yOfCompShips[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  for(int k = 0; k < xOfPlayersShips.length; k++) {
    if((xOfCompShips[i] == xOfCompShips[k] && yOfCompShips[i] == yOfCompShips[k]) ||
    (xOfCompShips[i] == xOfPlayersShips[k] && yOfCompShips[i] == yOfPlayersShips[k])){
      i--;
      **k--;**
      break;
    }
  }
}
```